# not working when trying to copy the values of a char matrix to another using recursivity

Tags: java, matrix

```
public static void igualacionMatrices(char [][]a,char [][]b,int i,int j) {

    if(i!=b.length && j!=b.length) {
        a[i][j]=b[i][j];

        if(j==b.length-1) {
            i++;
            j=0;
        }else {
            j++;
        }

        igualacionMatrices(a,b,i,j);
    }   

}
```

I have tried that but can't see what is wrong.
Matrix b got the values and both matrix have the same dimensions.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void igualacionMatrices(char [][]a,char [][]b,int i,int j) {

    if(i!=b.length && j!=b[i].length) {
        a[i][j]=b[i][j];

        if(j==b[i].length-1) {
            i++;
            j=0;
        }else {
            j++;
        }

        igualacionMatrices(a,b,i,j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that here you can use simple iteration with better results, as it is generally preferable to recursion. On large inputs recursion will blow your stack.